# How to change the color of matinput placeholder?

Tags: css, angular-material

how to style the color of placeholder? none of solutions published on stack overflow work for me.

```css
::ng-deep input.mat-input-element {
    color: #ff884d;
    caret-color: #ff884d;
}
```

```html
<form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input [(ngModel)]="email" matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl">
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Please enter a valid email address
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Email is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

All css styles are overwritten, but the color is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 100% it will Work

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-placeholder{
  color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder colour is a bit tricky, so use this selectors to avoid cross-browser issues:

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to overwrite the specific component Input placeholder.

```
:host /deep/ mat-form-field-placeholder{
  color: #ff884d;
}
```

If you want to overwrite the style in globally. then use your global stylesheet to overwrite using important keyword

```
mat-form-field-placeholder{
  color: #ff884d !important;
}
```